# Visual Studio 2012 app window creation/resizing differ from VS2008 window creation? Why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

@EDIT: I found out that it seems to be an issue of the Windows 8 RC, because I tried with Windows 7 and VS 2012, both classic and Aero view and it works fine. Thanks to @Werner Henze and @Ven Boigt for their feedback

EDIT 2: Turns out this was a bug in Windows due to being beta and it was fixed in newer revisions so I don't have to worry about this anymore. Thanks for the feedback anyway.

I used to do the following to create a window of an 800*600 client area:

```
dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX;
hWindowHandle = CreateWindow(   L"CGFramework", wszWndCaption, 
                            pWindowData->dwStyle, pWindowData->nPositionX, pWindowData->nPositionY, 
                            800 + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZEFRAME )*2, 
                            600 + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSIZEFRAME ) *2
                            + GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION ),
                            0, 0, hInstance, 0
                        );
```

Then when querying the client rect with GetClientRect, I used to get 800*600, but now I upgraded my Visual Studio 2008 project to VS2012, and now the GetClientRect() function is returning 792*592 instead.

On top of that, the actual size of the window being created is 804*629, for which I see no reason as the resizeable frame (from WS_THICKFRAME) is obviously larger than 2 pixels on each side.

I thought it was an issue of the Aero behaviour of Windows 8, but then I realized this is only happening with my VS2012 builds and not with my VS2008 builds. It makes no difference if I run it on Aero or the classic style, the behaviour will only apply to VS2012 builds. Why? Is there something I can change on my VS2012 project configuration to fix this horrible behaviour?

I tried changing "DPI Awareness" setting of the project config, but this is not making any difference. I also removed the use of manifest in the same config page, still don't see any change in the resulting window.

this is my test code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdio>

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( uMsg )
    {
    // WM_DESTROY is sent when the window is being destroyed.
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam );
    }
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd )
{

    WNDCLASS wc;
    wc.style                = NULL; // CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc          = MainWndProc; 
    wc.cbClsExtra           = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra           = 0;
    wc.hInstance            = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon                = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor              = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground        = CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE));
    wc.lpszMenuName         = 0;
    wc.lpszClassName        = L"CGFramework";
    DWORD dwStyle   = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_BORDER | 
                                WS_DLGFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX; // WS_DLGFRAME | 
    if( !RegisterClass(&wc) )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"RegisterClass FAILED", 0, 0);
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    RECT r;
    //r.left        = 100;
    //r.top     = 100;
    //r.right       = 800;
    //r.bottom  = 600;
    ////-----------------------------
    r.left      = 100;
    r.top       = 100;
    r.right     = 900;
    r.bottom    = 700;
    ////-----------------------------
    //r.left        = 100;
    //r.top     = 100;
    //r.right       = 800+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXFRAME )*2;
    //r.bottom  = 600+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYFRAME )*2+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION );

    BOOL result = AdjustWindowRect( &r, dwStyle, FALSE );

    HWND hWindowHandle = CreateWindow( L"CGFramework", L"testWindow", dwStyle,
                          r.left, r.top, r.right-r.left, r.bottom-r.top, 
                          // r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom, 
                          0, 0, hInstance, 0 );



    if( 0 == hWindowHandle )
    {
        MessageBox(0, L"CreateWindow FAILED", 0, 0);
        UnregisterClass( wc.lpszClassName, hInstance );
        return 0;
    }

    char buffer[512]; // for outing test message
    GetClientRect( hWindowHandle, &r );
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom );
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0); // print rect values before ShowWindow

    ShowWindow( hWindowHandle, SW_SHOW );

    GetClientRect( hWindowHandle, &r );
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom );
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0);  // print rect values after ShowWindow

    // main window loop
    MSG msg;
    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( MSG ) );
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT )
    {
        while( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) )
        {
            TranslateMessage( &msg );
            DispatchMessage( &msg );
        }

        if( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_ESCAPE ) )
            DestroyWindow( hWindowHandle );
    }
    UnregisterClass( wc.lpszClassName, hInstance );
    return 0;
}
```

Please watch carefullly the code before answering as you may end up answering something I already tried (I'm posting this question because I already wasted all my choices).

I'm using Windows 8 RC (MS windows 6.2.8400) and VS2012 RC (11.0.50706.0 QRELRC July 2012) to get this weird behaviour and none of the kind answers were able to address this issue. Be sure of reading them and testing my code before making any assumptions, as this code has been tested in many ways with subtle differences which in the end provided no improvement.

Comment: They might have added (...or just enabled) non-standard screen DPI support.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using `AdjustWindowRect()`?

Comment: @Deanna I'd rather change my VS2012 project configuration instead of changing source code I know to work as expected with my old project configuration. I don't see a reason to modify my code if it works fine with the proper config. I won't start making changes in the code for each project configuration unless there is no other way.

Comment: @Pablo: Using [`AdjustWindowRectEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632667.aspx) wouldn't mean multiple versions of the code for different configurations.  It is available as far back as Windows 2000.  And you could get rid of the multiple `GetSystemMetrics` calls.

Comment: @PabloAriel: There is a reason API calls like that exist rather than making assumptions on the size of various components. I know you're asking for values from Windows, but you're still making an assumption that there are no other values involved.

Comment: @Deanna: maybe you can help me on how to use properly the AdjustWindowRect function? It seems I'm doing something wrong..

Comment: @Deanna your api call won't solve anything and my way of doing it works perfectly fine and it's been researched enough (your API call will yield the same results as my previous code). There's a reason why API calls are documented and they answer to standard behaviour, not a random result you can't rely on. If result of API calls are random, then it would be a poor designed API, wouldn't it? But the result of my call is predictable the same way as your fancy API call. And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others stated `AdjustWindowRect` or `AdjustWindowRectEx` is the way to go. You need to do special handling if `WS_VSCROLL` or `WS_HSCROLL` is set. In my util library I also have special handling for `WS_EX_STATICEDGE`, but don't ask me where I got this information from (at least it's not in the MSDN documentation for `AdjustWindowRect[Ex]`).

The bug in your latest test was that you are calling `CreateWindow` the wrong way, it takes a width and height, not right and bottom. This should work as required:

```
dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_BORDER | WS_DLGFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX; 
RECT r; 
r.left      = 100; 
r.top       = 100; 
r.right     = 900; 
r.bottom    = 700; 
BOOL result = AdjustWindowRect( &r, dwStyle, FALSE ); 
hWindowHandle = CreateWindow( L"CGFramework", wszWndCaption, pWindowData->dwStyle,
                              pWindowData->nPositionX, pWindowData->nPositionY,  
                              r.left, r.top, r.right-r.left, r.bottom-r.top, 
                              0, 0, hInstance, 0 );
```

And just for information, here is the complete sample:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <Windows.h> 
#include <cstdio> 
#include <cassert>

LRESULT CALLBACK MainWndProc( HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam ) 
{ 
    switch( uMsg ) 
    { 
    // WM_DESTROY is sent when the window is being destroyed. 
    case WM_DESTROY: 
        PostQuitMessage(0); 
        return 0; 
    default: 
        return DefWindowProc( hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam ); 
    } 
} 

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, INT nShowCmd ) 
{ 

    WNDCLASS wc; 
    wc.style                = NULL; // CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW; 
    wc.lpfnWndProc          = MainWndProc;  
    wc.cbClsExtra           = 0; 
    wc.cbWndExtra           = 0; 
    wc.hInstance            = hInstance; 
    wc.hIcon                = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION); 
    wc.hCursor              = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW); 
    wc.hbrBackground        = CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE)); 
    wc.lpszMenuName         = 0; 
    wc.lpszClassName        = L"CGFramework"; 
    DWORD dwStyle   = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_BORDER |  
                                WS_DLGFRAME | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX; 
    if( !RegisterClass(&wc) ) 
    { 
        MessageBox(0, L"RegisterClass FAILED", 0, 0); 
        return E_FAIL; 
    } 

    RECT r; 
    //r.left        = 100; 
    //r.top     = 100; 
    //r.right       = 800; 
    //r.bottom  = 600; 
    ////----------------------------- 
    r.left      = 100; 
    r.top       = 100; 
    r.right     = 900; 
    r.bottom    = 700; 
    ////----------------------------- 
    //r.left        = 100; 
    //r.top     = 100; 
    //r.right       = 800+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CXSIZEFRAME )*2; 
    //r.bottom  = 600+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYSIZEFRAME )*2+GetSystemMetrics( SM_CYCAPTION ); 

    BOOL result = AdjustWindowRect( &r, dwStyle, FALSE ); 
    assert(result);
    char buffer[512]; 
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "adjust left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom ); 
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0); 

    HWND hWindowHandle = CreateWindow(  L"CGFramework", L"Window Test", dwStyle, r.left, r.top, r.right-r.left, r.bottom-r.top, 0, 0, hInstance, 0 );  

    if( 0 == hWindowHandle ) 
    { 
        MessageBox(0, L"CreateWindow FAILED", 0, 0); 
        UnregisterClass( wc.lpszClassName, hInstance ); 
        return 0; 
    } 

    assert(GetWindowRect(hWindowHandle, &r));
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "wnd left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom ); 
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0); 

    GetClientRect( hWindowHandle, &r ); 
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "style=%08x/%08x, exstyle=%08x, left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", GetWindowLong(hWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE), dwStyle, GetWindowLong(hWindowHandle, GWL_EXSTYLE), r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom ); 
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0); 

    ShowWindow( hWindowHandle, SW_SHOW ); 

    GetClientRect( hWindowHandle, &r ); 
    sprintf( &buffer[0], "left=%i, top=%i, right=%i, bottom=%i", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom ); 
    MessageBoxA(0, buffer, 0, 0); 

    MSG msg; 
    ZeroMemory( &msg, sizeof( MSG ) ); 
    while( msg.message != WM_QUIT ) 
    { 
        while( PeekMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE ) ) 
        { 
            TranslateMessage( &msg ); 
            DispatchMessage( &msg ); 
        } 

        if( GetAsyncKeyState( VK_ESCAPE ) ) 
            DestroyWindow( hWindowHandle ); 
    } 

    UnregisterClass( wc.lpszClassName, hInstance ); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it won't work, I already tried that, I know it's weird but believe me I already tried everything I could think of.

Comment: @Pablo Ariel: Did you test my code snippet? Did you see the change in the call to CreateWindow? I tested this code, it works. I just pasted the complete sample file, please copy it and test it.

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work, but I see no difference with my current code (you can see yesterday I applied your line to my code). Probably it was a problem with the project file, because I made a new project again and now the same code works perfectly fine. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: But do you think in the end the CreateWindow function behaves different from previous versions? I still don't know why when building with VS2008 I don't need to use AdjustWindowRect, but when upgrading to VS2012 I can't rely on my previous technique.

Comment: @Pablo Ariel: As Ben Voigt said CreateWindow is part of the Windows API, so does not depend on the compiler used. But CreateWindow might use information provided in the exe's manifest. You might compare those two. Also if you have one good project file and one bad project file, it should be easy to compare those and track down the relevant change.

Answer (score 6):

The `CreateWindow` function is part of the Windows API, it is not provided by Visual Studio, and Visual Studio version doesn't affect it.

The most likely explanation is that the default project settings in VS2012 added a manifest that marks the application as Aero-aware or DPI-aware, and the presence of that manifest changes the behavior of WinAPI functions.  You can edit or remove the manifest to get the old behavior.

It's also possible, but less likely, that Windows is checking the "minimum OS version" field in the PE header.  Newer versions of the linker usually drop support for writing older versions into this field, but the `editbin` tool can be used to change it post-link.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `AdjustWindowRectEx` and make sure the style and extended style matches *exactly* the final styles that the window will use.  e.g. if you set some additional style some time after `CreateWindow`, even if done automatically by some library, you must also set the corresponding style for `AdjustWindowRectEx`.  You might want to retrieve the style after creation to see if Windows or some library added styles.

If you use scrollbars you should factor that in too.

Comment: I'm not using scrollbars, you can try just creating an empty win32 project and copying and pasting the code I supplied (it's a complete program), it won't work properly on VS 2012 but works fine on VS 2008. It's not a complicated program, just a basic window creation, it shuold take no time to check if it works properly for you.

Comment: I tried with AdjustEx  and CreateEx functions and won't make any difference, thanks anyway.